# CSRF Token Mismatched on server though it's working fine on localhost

Tags: laravel, next.js, laravel-sanctum

I am working on a project (Laravel API - Sanctum & NextJs). Logging in and everything is working fine on localhost and postman but it shows 'CSRF Token Mismatched' after deploying on the server.

admin.example.com is the subdomain where I deployed the NextJs app. I updated the main domain and subdomain in sanctum.php as follows.

sanctum.php

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,localhost:8000::1,example.com, admin.example.ae',
        env('APP_URL') ? ',' . parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : '',
        env('FRONTEND_URL') ? ',' . parse_url(env('FRONTEND_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
    ))),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this.

If you are just starting to add `Sanctum` to your project or about to go live with Sanctum, please make sure you configured all the mentioned settings on [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#spa-configuration) of `Laravel Sanctum Docs`. I have mentioned them in a summary below.

- If you are working on localhost and it has port (eg. 8000), please send the request from your frontend app to `http://localhost:8000` instead of `http://localhost`.
- Make sure `supports_credentials` is `true` on `config/cors.php`
- Set `withCredentials` to `true` on your `global Axios configuration` of frontend
- Make sure *your application's session cookie domain configuration supports any subdomain of your root domain* by configuring this `'domain' => '.example.com',` at `config/session.php` file or add this `SESSION_DOMAIN=".example.com"` to your `.env` file

As I mentioned above, please go through and read [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#spa-configuration) of Laravel Sanctum Docs again if it still doesn't work.

If you can't even make the request from Postman, please read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74839558/cant-log-in-to-laravel-api-on-staging-server-laravel-forge-via-nextjs-or-post) that mentions what I experienced at the same time.